# I want to see order information

Tags: orders

I want to view purchase item information in sales, orders. i do not see an option to show this information, like what item the person actually bought.

Comment: Can you please specify Magento Version.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Sales > Orders, select an order and then scroll down, you should see something similar to this:

[image]

(This is for Magento 2.1.x, not sure which version you are running)

Comment: thanks. there's no way to show it on the first page before clicking on the actual order? i ask because we get many orders, but only some need action, and it's nice to easily see which products need to be acted upon, and not have to open up all orders.

Comment: @ChrissyWolcott I don't believe there is a way to view the actual products ordered without opening the order, not without building some custom functionality into magento.

Comment: This will need a custom development to create a popup for quick view for order inside admin.